# using java main method load SpringContext, Annatation Can't get the bean

Tags: spring

Using `Java` main method load `SpringContext`. `Annatation` can't get the bean.

Java method code:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"spring-mybatis.xml"});

    context.start();
    UserMapper userMapper = (UserMapper)context.getBean("userMapper");
    System.out.println("userMapper----->:" + userMapper);   //this line can get the bean,and print the bean's Memory Address
    while(true){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

But when I using the `Annatation` get the bean, can not get it,return the NULL
java code:

```
@Resource

private UserMapper userMapper;
```

Comment: There can be a number of reasons for this. What does your XML look like? How is the `userMapper` bean defined? Is the class in which `userMapper` is injected also a Spring bean? (If not, dependency injection doesn't work).

Comment: hello,The userMapper is Mybatis interface,The are in spring-batis.xml,It use mybatis scan tool to work it,Now this is the spring-mybatis.xml configuration:<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
  <property name="basePackage" value="com.dream.common.dao" />
  <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory"></property>

 </bean>